How to differentiate coyote vs wolf tracks
I spotted these canine paw prints in the snow on crown (public) land in Eastern Ontario, Canada. They're not dog prints; the location is too remote for that.
I figure the only options are coyote or wolf. How can I differentiate between the two?


The most noteworthy way to differentiate is by size. Wolves are bigger:

 Image source: WDFW 
Regarding the size of young wolves (from here):

Young wolves’ feet grow large very quickly, and by the time they are about three months old (around July) even young wolves’ tracks are larger than most coyote tracks

Some additional characteristics from the Washington Department of Fish and Wildlife :

Wolf tracks are about 5 inches long by 4 inches wide, with four symmetrical toes and evident claws, and a single lobe on the front of the foot pad. Coyote tracks are similar, but about half that size, and even the largest domestic dog breeds usually have smaller tracks. The paths of wolves usually show a direct, energy efficient or purposeful route, whereas those of dogs often meander.


It'd be pretty hard to tell in soft snow like in the question, but there are some pretty obvious differences in the print that I can see in the image you supplied - front toes aimed together for the coyote and the pad has a central bump as opposed to the arch seen on the wolf.

Great answer, and one I'll remember next time I'm alone in a snowy forest far from civilization. @bob1 - How do you know so much stuff???

Regarding young wolves/etc - would the ratio of paw size to stride length also give evidence for/against?

What's the verdict on the picture's tracks, then?

Coywolf seems like another option to consider, especially given OP's location.

@anongoodnurse Fair bit of an autodidact, academic access to libraries and moderately good at use of search terms to find what I want to know...

The answer by theforestecologist covers the basics of differentiating the tracks, so I won’t repeat that in detail here.
As for the actual tracks pictured, they are too large for a coyote, which suggests either a wolf or a dog, but they’re a bit on the small side for a wolf, which would suggest either a young wolf or a large dog. The stride length isn’t a huge help in differentiating, as there are plenty of dog breeds that have that short of a stride relative to the size of their paws.
Beyond that it would require seeing both the overall path taken, and the area in general. For example, if the path the tracks take is meandering significantly it’s probably a dog (wolves generally don’t wander aimlessly or get constantly distracted like many dogs do), while a lack of accompanying human tracks nearby would make it all but certain that these are wolf tracks (if it were a dog in such a remote area, it would almost certainly be accompanied by a human).
